# Is there a way to restart a SystemDriver using get-WmiObject or get-CimInstance using Powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, devops

I am grabbing the state of a SystemDriver using:

```
get-ciminstance -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver WHERE Name='supercooldriver'"
```

However, what I need to do is, restart the driver using Powershell (or stop and start it again). Currently, I am having to reboot my machine every time I need it to restart and it's becoming taxing.

I have looked at the docs on it and I have attempted the StopService() route and I got a ReturnValue of 5.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of driver is it?  Is it a file system filter driver for example you can unload with fltmc.exe?  Are you running "StopService" as admin given the error 5 (access denied)?

Comment: It is indeed a file system driver. I tried to unload with ftmc.exe after your suggestion and got an "Unload failed with error: Do not detach the filter from the volume at this time" error.

Comment: Chances are there is one or more user mode applications with a handle to it. Do you know if there is a service/process that is associated with the driver?  If you stop the service(s) and/or kill the process(es) can you stop it then? Maybe use Process Explorer and search for handles that contain the name of the driver as a hint.

Comment: There is an application that used it (involving a service, yes). I uninstalled the app and this driver is left behind. The only way to get rid of it is to reboot the machine. Apparently, it's a kernel system driver, and therefore, is not possible to interact with it like we would with a normal service/driver.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with this driver, you said initially " I am having to reboot my machine every time I need it to restart".  The software that the driver is bundled with you have uninstalled.  So why do you need the driver?  You could just remove the .sys file or run `sc.exe delete [drivername]`.